# How to get absolute path of file which Apache reported 404 not found?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, vhosts

When it comes to `http://www.example.com/normal/url/path`, Apache replied `404 Not Found`, but wait, I know there is `normal/url/path` in the directory of `ScriptAlias` pointed to, I mean in the `vhost` config file.

Sadly, I only have `"GET /normal/url/path HTTP/1.1" 404` in the log file of Apache, actually I want to see something like this, `"GET /opt/www/location/normal/url/path HTTP/1.1" 404`, I think this is clearer, effective, How do I to config this...

Comment: The access log shows incoming requests before being processed by rewrites, etc.  Where you'd want this is in the error log.  In fact it's probably already in the error log.  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/994711/63361). In particular, you can add `%f` to a [custom log format](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats).